# How to 'git status' only working tree changes in git?

Tags: git

I'm using Git v2.8 and I'd like to be able to run `git status` and ONLY show changes that are *not* staged in the index (including untracked files). This is useful in cases where I'm adding small bits of files at a time to the index, but the list of files in the index that I've staged so far is huge, and gets in the way of seeing what is left to actually stage.

Is there a way to do this? Preferably with the same coloring scheme used by `git status`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to write your own script to do this. What's wrong with just committing your large amount of staged changes? Temporary commits are totally fine in git land.

Comment: since it's a visualization issue, "git status --short" isn't enough?

Comment: `git diff` instead. `git diff --cached` for the staged.

Answer (score 0):

Display files that are modified but all the modifications are not in the index yet, or are not tracked.  The coloring is lost.

```
git status -s | grep -e"^ M" -e"^??" -e"^MM"
```